# Add new line after print array

Tags: linux, bash

I am saving some values into an array and when doing the printf a newline don't appears

```
declare array=( $(echo $line | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{printf $NF}') )
printf "%s " "${array[@]}"
```

The output:

```
Value1 Value2 Value3
```

But the cursor is on the same line and need to do a new line.

Other action I do it are to add another printf:

```
declare array=( $(echo $line | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{printf $NF}') )
printf "%s " "${array[@]}"; printf "%s\n"
```

But the output in this case are:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

What is wrong?
The complete code is:

```
while IFS="" read -r line; do
    declare array=( $(echo $line | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{printf $NF}') )
    printf "%s " "${array[@]}"
done < <(tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 0 port bootps | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname')
```

and the output:

```
6c:56:97:3c:6f:51 10.0.1.10 WINC
```

The output of tcpdump is:

```
[root@PIDORA ~]# tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 0 port bootps
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:21:09.177072 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 325)
    0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 6c:56:97:3c:6f:51, length 297, xid 0x3a1e3c9a, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address 6c:56:97:3c:6f:51
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Request
        Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 6c:56:97:3c:7f:51
        Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 10.0.1.14
        MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1500
        Vendor-Class Option 60, length 15: "WINC"
        Hostname Option 12, length 10: "WINC"
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 3: 
          Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server
        END Option 255, length 0
```

Comment: Add output of `echo "$line"` and desired output to your question.

Comment: if put this:
 `declare array=( $(echo $line | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{printf $NF}') )
 printf "%s " "${array[@]}"
 echo $line`

the output:

`Value1 Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether Value1
Value2 Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: Value2
Value3 Hostname Option 12, length 10: "Value3"`

Comment: ... to your question.

Comment: Why `printf "%s\n"`? Did you mean `printf "\n"`?

Comment: no. Without \n can't see all values in one line. This is right. But If I put \n see every values in new lines

Comment: You're confused. The code you posted here doesn't match the output you claim to get. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: update with all code

Comment: I'm confused too. What's the input that causes your first sample code to produce `Value1 Value2 Value3`?

Comment: @ghoti an example output. The complete output is in last edit

Comment: *What is the input ...*

Answer (score 0):

It is rather unusual to set `IFS` before calling `read` with a single destination variable (in your case `line`) since `IFS` is used to split **one line of input into several words**.

For example:

```
read var0 var1 var2 <<< "abc def ghi"
printf 'var0="%s" var1="%s" var2="%s"\n' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

will print: `var0="abc" var1="def" var2="ghi"`

Using `IFS=""`:

```
unset var0 var1 var2
IFS="" read var0 var1 var2 <<< "abc def ghi"
printf 'var0="%s" var1="%s" var2="%s"\n' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

You will get: `var0="abc def ghi" var1="" var2=""`

My guess is you set `IFS=""` because you thought `IFS` controlled how lines are split when in fact, that parameter is controlled by the `-d` option of `read`.

With that in mind, you may want to try to following:

```
while read -r -d "" line; do
    declare -a array=($(sed 's/"//g' <<< "$line" | awk '{print $NF}'))
    printf '%s ' "${array[@]}"
    printf '\n'
done < <(tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 0 port bootps | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname')
```

But it won't work. `read` returns a non-zero error code when reaching `EOF` which it will on the first call if it ignores every newline. That only proves one thing: the while loop is useless.

If I am right, the following "one-liner" should work just fine:

```
tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 0 port bootps |
    grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname' |
    awk '{print $NF}' |
    tr -d '"' |
    tr '\n' ' '; printf '\n'
```

Comment: I just realised the `while read -d "" line; do ...` is not gonna work as I expected. Updated my answer about that

Comment: Can you try the last code block in my answer, please? I tried it with the output you provided and it worked just find =)

Comment: no output results... only show results until **awk '{print $NF}'**. When put **tr** no see nothing.

Comment: Well, that's surprising! `tr` really doesn't do much, the first one removes quotation marks and the second one replaces newlines with spaces. Are you sure you copy pasted the code correctly?

Comment: I mean, if you don't believe me, you can try running it [there](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online) (simply replace `tcpdump ...` with `cat -` and place the output you provided in your question in the "Stdin inputs" box).

Comment: but not's possible to added a new line after print the array?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's just that you are mistaken as to what is in the array. There is only one value in that array, and you do 3 loop iterations, hence the 3 new lines you get when you add the `printf '\n'` part. You can convince yourself about this by printing "$#" before printing the array.

Comment: yes. it's a value '0'. But can't print this 3 lines into one line and put finally a newline?

Comment: Woops, I meant `${#array[@]}` (that's the number of element in `array`. `$#` is just the number of arguments you pass to your program). More to the point though, yes you can print 3 lines into one and add a final newline. For that, `tr` and [`man tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) are your friends.

Comment: but when I add **tr** after array not output

Comment: I understand, but I have no idea why. You should update your question to reflect how you tried my suggestions and show that it did not work. I'll check tomorrow, and in the meantime, someone else might figure it out.

Comment: and it's possible to do a loop and break into a newline when have 3 arguments?